# What is the proper way to halt a QThread worker processing a resource that is about to be deleted?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

Here is some pseudo-code to explain my situation. I am using QThreads, but the solution may be Qt agnostic.

```
class ResourceOwner
{
  // Spawns worker on new QThread, initiates Worker::doWork()
 void spawnWorker(resource); {...}

 void deleteResourceSafely(); // How do you implement this function?

private:
 Resource *resource;
 Worker *worker;
}

class Worker
{
 void doWork() { while(true) resource->doSomething(); }
 void cleanupSelf() {...};
private:
 Resource *resource;
}

void main()
{
  ResourceOwner owner();
  owner.spawnWorker();
  ...
  // Some time later after enough work has been done
  owner.deleteResourceSafely();
}
```

When it is time to delete `resource` we need to shut down the worker. However, the `Worker` might be in the middle of accessing `resource`.

If `resource` is just deleted, then `Worker` will crash because it accesses invalid memory. I could just stop the thread that the `Worker` belongs to, but then `Worker` wouldn't get a chance to clean itself up properly.

So I how do I interrupt `Worker`'s `doWork()` function to tell it to clean itself up and stop accessing `resource`?

Answer (score 1):

A common and simple way is to have a flag that the thread checks at regular intervals. If it's set then the thread terminates it self.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using Qt already, I would suggest that the thread attempting to delete the resource should send a signal to the worker thread, then wait for the worker thread to terminate as a result of the signal. Obviously you need to implement an appropriate signal handler.

Comment: I think this sounds like an elegant way to do this - but `doWork()` never gives processing back to the `QThread`, so the slot would never get called. Also, `QThread` doesn't seem to have a `processEvents()` function similar to that of `QEventLoop` or `QCoreApplication`.

Comment: You can add an event loop to a qthread but you must ensure it gets processing time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by joachim, have a flag that you periodically check in the worker thread.  Add a function to Worker called something like requestStop that sets a volatile bool or maybe a QAtomicInt to false to indicate the thread should exit run ().  Use a volatile bool to ensure that the compiler does not optimize out accesses to it.  Your work item should check this flag frequently and if it becomes false it should ensure that it returns from run () asap..  What wasn't mentioned is that after setting the flag, call wait () on the thread for it to exit.  Once the call to wait () returns, the thread has stopped so it is safe to delete the Resource.

A partial alternative is to use a reference counted resource to avoid the call to wait().  If your resource has a shared pointer to it in the worker thread then if the main thread drops its reference to it and flags the thread (or work item) to complete, the Worker thread/item can remove its reference to it when completed and destroy it if it was the sole remaining owner.  I.e. This aproach will work with threadpools where you wouldn't wait on the thread to complete as work items are queued instead.